# Running Eclipse on HP 14 Chromebook with crouton and xfce. When ever I enter in Eclipse screen turns black

Tags: java, eclipse, chromebook, xfce, crouton-os

Ok, so I am a standing at the beginning on my relationship to linux and spend the last couple of days to get Eclipse running on my Chromebook using crouton.

Now I ran into this really weird problem:

When ever I start Eclipse everything works fine. I open my new project and Class and want to begin my long journey of finally really learning Java.
Typing works fine but as soon as I hit enter my screen turns black.
I can resolve this issue by switching back to my ChromeOS and back to XFCE again. Pressing enter again however turns my screen black again.
This usually happens 2-3 times. After that it works fine as far as I can tell. Hitting backspace has a similar effect but in reverse. It works fine until i hit a certain point. Typing while the screen is black works fine btw..

What can that be? I'm happy to try and provide pretty much everything you need to help me fix this issue.

UPDATE:
I just found out that when i press the little minus or plus symbol to collapse or expand lines it also goes black. Maybe thats a vital clue?

Comment: I've never heard of any software that did THAT before, unless there was a problem with the video card or drivers. But then again, you are talking about a Chromebook, and I'm not too familiar with them. Does this happen with Eclipse only?

Comment: Only Eclipse yes. And its so oddly specific that i burst into laughter when i first encounterd this bug. Maybe out of despair maybe out of frustration..

Comment: That is so weird... If you haven't already, try reinstalling Eclipse and see if that helps.

Comment: Try using Intellij. It's much better than Eclipse IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 will try! And will keep you up to date if this is also causing weird screen problems.

Comment: @cricket_007 Intellij works okay. up until now! Thank you! Guess the eclipse problem will just fade into obscurity. If someone still comes up with a solution tho I will try it out. Maybe in the future some else will run into the same problem!

Comment: @cricket_007 telling the user to switch to a different IDE is no solution. Which is better is purely down to opinion.

Comment: @SnakeDoc - Which is why I didn't post an answer, I made a comment, which apparently let the OP continue on his way to learning Java.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse uses SWT which poorly integrates with GTK. Try running eclipse with SWT_GTK3=0 in environment.